# Bootstrap 3 navigation toggle button always appearing in IE11 (on remote server)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing a very strange behaviour with Bootstrap 3 when viewing in Internet Explorer. My nav bar works perfectly locally (I'm using VS2012, so the page is being served by IIS Express), but when I deploy it to one of our internal servers (running full IIS) it always appears collapsed (even if I stretch the browser across both my monitors!)

If I user Chrome, it works perfectly.

I've compared the files that are downloaded in each case, and they are identical. I have even create a test file which uses the example nav bar from the bootstrap website, and I see the same behaviour.

So, to summarize:

```
Local / IE          Works
Local / Chrome      Works
Remote / IE         Does not work
Remote / Chrome     Works
```

Any pointers about this very strange behaviour would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Microsoft Edge   -- works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, and it is Internet Explorer's compatibility settings.

Under Tools > Compatibility View Settings dialog there is a checkbox which says *"Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"*.

[image]

This setting meant IE used an older rendering engine, which did not work very well with Bootstrap. Once it was turned off everything was fine.